# Index and RLS on Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have table data1 with 2 field: user_id and data_id. I have 2 indexes on user_id and data_id. They are a non unique indexed.

a function:

```
FUNCTION user_filter(p_schema IN VARCHAR2,
                                   p_object IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'user_id='||session_pkg.user_id;
  END;
```

I register this function as rls policy on data1:

```
DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY(OBJECT_SCHEMA   => '',
                        OBJECT_NAME     => 'data1',
                        POLICY_NAME     => 'user_filter',
                        POLICY_FUNCTION => 'user_filter');
```

To have best performance, do I have to create 1 more Index like following?

```
create index data3_idx on data (user_ID, data_id);
```

Thanks,

Comment: do you mean that I will need 02 index: on (user_id,data_id) and on data_id? Some time we will remove RLS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it would be wasteful to have three indexes for two columns `(data_id)`, `(user_id,data_id)` and `(user_id)` since Oracle can use the compound index for queries that filter on `user_id` and queries that filter on both columns.

In your case the `DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY` procedure will add the filter `user_id=XX` to all requests on this object. This means that you could replace the index on `data_id` with a more efficient compound index.

Comment: Hi Vincent Malgrat, some times, I will remove RLS. I will keep 2 indexes: (user_id,data_id) and (data_id)?

Comment: Yes, if some queries don't use RLS and you need to query your data by `data_id` these two indexes should be fine.